# MSSQL Database: Log not cleared after COMMIT TRANSACTION

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

**edit: Thanks for all the hints. Meanwhile, the problem has solved itself.
I do not know why but it works now. Weird...**

I have a MSSQL Database which is in **Recovery Mode Simple** and there is this Stored Procedure:

```
BEGIN TRY 
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    exec prcDownSyncOrganisationalUnit;
    exec prcDownSyncOrganisationalUnitPeriod;
    exec prcDownSyncPerson;
    exec prcUpSyncPersonLogin;
    exec prcDownSyncOrganisationalUnitPerson;
    exec prcDownSyncAddress;
    exec prcDownSyncLocation;
    exec prcDownSyncLocationAddress;
    exec prcDownSyncOrganisationalUnitLocation;
    exec prcDownSyncTour;
    exec prcDownSyncDisplayType;
    exec prcDownSyncOperator;
    exec prcDownSyncList;
    exec prcDownSyncListEntry;
    exec prcDownSyncQuestionnaire;
    exec prcDownSyncOrganisationalUnitQuestionnaire;
    exec prcDownSyncQuestionnaireGroup;
    exec prcDownSyncQuestionnaireGroupQuestion;
    exec prcDownSyncExpressionGroup;
    exec prcDownSyncExpressionGroupMember;
    exec prcDownSyncExpressionAssignment;
    exec prcDownSyncQuestionnaireGroupQuestionExpression;
    exec prcDownSyncQuestionnaireGroupQuestionMapping;
    exec prcBiSyncAppointment;
    exec prcBiSyncAppointmentStatus;
    exec prcDownSyncAppointmentStatusEvent;
    exec prcDownSyncAppointmentAssignment;
    exec prcBiSyncAppointmentQuestionnaireResult;
    exec prcBiSyncAppointmentQuestionnaireResultAnswer;
    exec prcBiSyncAppointmentQuestionnaireResultAnswerHistory;
    --exec prcBiSyncDocument;
    exec prcDownSyncAppointmentXmlValue;
    exec prcDownSyncPromoter;
    --exec prcRemoveDeletedData;

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH 
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

    EXEC prcErrorRaise;
    THROW;

END CATCH
```

This Procedure runs every 5 minutes and forces the Log to grow 500MB by every execution. After the Procedure successfully completed, the Log is not cleared. So after some time the Log is really really big and impacts performance.

Any ideas what i can do? Why is the Log not cleared?

Comment: Try and force a truncation of the log with a checkpoint

Comment: Log files do not automatically shrink themselves. Expanding the log files is an expensive operation. If this is going to happen routinely the file is just going to grow again so you are not going to help things by shrinking the log file. But how is the size of the log file impacting performance?

Comment: @SeanLange Because on every execution the Log file is growing by 500MB. After one day the disk is full and i think the full disk has a impact on the performace (I should have mentioned that at the beginning). So there are some data in the Log that get never cleared. But in Recovery Mode Simple this should happen after a transaction completed.

Comment: Well absolutely a full disc will affect performance. You say the log file is growing every few minutes by 500MB? Sounds like something is not right there. In simple mode it shouldn't be growing the log that much assuming you deal with the open transaction.

Comment: What kind of LOG are you talking here? Is it built-in log or the log you implemented? If the second, could you please expand on that, provide some details?

Comment: @OPunktSchmidt Can you look at sys.databases and tell us the value in the log_reuse_wait_desc column, for the impacted database

Comment: @PeteCarter  Thanks for the hint. log_reuse_wait_desc for my database is "NOTHING" so I think this is okay. But the problem has now solved over the weekend by itself. Weird...

Answer (score 1):

I would say we need more information. If you have a non-production environment that mirrors production run these tests on it, but in any case:

Run  DBCC SQLPERF(logspace) to see current log status
Run (inside a transaction ) each proc listed in you wrapper script.
Commit
ReRun DBCC SQLPERF(logspace)

Does the log file size jump after one of those calls? If so there's a topic to bring up with your developers.

This may be of help also:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1178/monitoring-sql-server-database-transaction-log-space/

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But the problem has now solved over the weekend by itself. Weird... .So log file size does not change after the call of DBCC SQLPERF(logspace).